# Show the collection of sets M is basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am self studying topology using Topology without Tears

Let $C[0,1]$ be set of all real valued continuous functions

Show the collection $M$ given by
$$
M=\{M(f,\epsilon),f\in  C[0,1]\}, \quad
M(f,\epsilon) = \{g:g \in C[0,1] \text{ and } \int_0^1 |f-g| < \epsilon\}
$$

Show this a basis  for $\tau_1$

Ok I saw a bunch of hints
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1195168/830852

Here goes nothing

Let $\epsilon = 1$. Suppose $f\in M(f,1)$ then
$\int_0^1 |f-f|=0 <1$ so
$C[0,1] =\bigcup M(f,1)$ for $f\in C[0,1]$.

For the rest of it I thought prop. 2.3.2 would
apply somehow

I also thought of using triangle inequality on
the integral.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: I will change it

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $\mathcal M = \{M(f,\epsilon),f\in  C[0,1]\}$ is a basis for $\tau_1$. You don't say what $\tau_1$ is, but from the context it seems that $\tau_1$ is the topology over $C[0,1]$ induced by the metric
$$
d(f,g) = \int_0^1 |f-g|.
$$
Let's review the definition of a basis:

> A basis for a topology $\tau$ over a space $X$ is a collection of open subsets (elements of $\tau$ such that
>
> 1. The base elements cover $X$
> 2. Let $B_1$, $B_2$ be base elements. Then for each $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there is a base element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

First, you should verify that the elements of $\mathcal M$  are open. Then, you should show that part 1 of the definition holds (which is what you have done with your argument so far). The tricky part is showing that the second part of the definition applies to 1.

With that in mind: let $B_1 = M(f_1,\epsilon_1)$ and $B_2 = M(f_2,\epsilon_2)$. If $B_1 \cap B_2 = \emptyset$, then there is nothing to show. So, suppose that $B_1 \cap B_2$ is non-empty. Let $g$ be an element of $B_1 \cap B_2$.  By definition, this means that
$$
d(f_1,g) < \epsilon_1, \quad d(f_2,g) < \epsilon_2.
$$
Now, define $\delta = \min\{\epsilon_1 - d(f_1,g),\epsilon_2 - d(f_2,g)\}$. **Using the triangle inequality**, show that if a function $h \in C[0,1]$ satisfies $d(g,h) < \delta$, then it also satisfies $d(f_1,h) < \epsilon_1$ and $d(f_2,h) < \epsilon_2$. Using this fact, conclude that the basis element $B_3 = M(g,\delta)$ contains $g$ and satisfies $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Comment: It is on C[0,1]